# How to draw table with Google Datatable Using PHP & jQuery Ajax Json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, google-visualization

I am trying to create table using google datatable with Ajax & json.When user selected  file from selectbox , it gets file datas as json with php & jquery ajax.

Here is sample json datas:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

Here is my jQuery Ajax Calls:

```
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  $(document).on("change","select#source",function(){

            var source=$("select#source option:selected").attr("value");    



                function drawTable() {

                  var jsonData = $.ajax({
                      url: "google_charts_data_preview_ajax.php",
                      data:{source:source},
                      dataType:"json",
                      async: false
                      }).responseText;

                  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.

                  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

                  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('g_table'));

                  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});


                }

        });
```

After all this an error ocuring on console.Error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: drawTable is not defined
```

Google tells how to create charts using json.I applied what they says.But I couldnt figured out what is mistake what I had done?.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

How can achive this?

Thanks

Comment: have you loaded all the required files before calling drawTable? This error means that javascript doesn't know what this function is and what it does.

Comment: Have you included also [code]<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>[/code]??

Comment: Yes I loaded <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> jquery library

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple scope problem. You must move your `drawTable()` function outside the `$(document).on("change",..` handler, into the global scope. `google.setOnLoadCallback` cannot see `drawTable` since it is hidden inside the handler.

```
function drawTable() {
     var source=$("select#source option:selected").attr("value");    
     var jsonData = $.ajax({
         url: "google_charts_data_preview_ajax.php",
         data: {
             source: source
         },
         dataType: "json",
         async: false
     }).responseText;

     // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
     var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('g_table'));
     table.draw(data, {
         showRowNumber: true
     });
 }
```

and

```
$(document).on("change","select#source",function(){
   drawTable();
});
```

proof that this actual is the problem and the code otherwise works great -> **http://jsfiddle.net/411gosq7/**